# Proving $SAS$ provided other congruence criteria

Tags: geometry

In his book *Elementary Geometry from an Advanced Standpoint*, E. E. Moise states the *SAS* congruence criterion as a postulate and prove *ASA* and *SSS* with it.

If one introduces *ASA* or *SSS* as a postulate (without stating *SAS* as a postulate), *SAS* can be proved as a theorem?

Comment: This will depend on the other postulates/axioms

Comment: Can we use the Pythogoras theorem?

Comment: @QED No, we cannot. Pythagoras theorem is equivalent to Parallel postulate, and it appears after SAS.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen We have all of the postulates of incidence and angles, and the Plane-Separation postulate.